# Need to add header on this table

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am trying to fetch data from SQlite DB and show it in `JTable` - but header not appear.

This my code:

```
JPanel panel =new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(null);
panel.setSize(5,5);

JTable tabel_1=new JTable();
tabel_1.setSelectionBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 153, 51));

JTableHeader header=tabel_1.getTableHeader();
header.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

DefaultTableModel tableModel =(DefaultTableModel) DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs);

tableModel.setColumnIdentifiers(headers);

tabel_1.setModel(tableModel);
frame.add(panel);

frame.add(tabel_1);
```

and this is result:

[image]

Comment: Add the table in a JScrollPane

Comment: `panel.setLayout(null);` Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `JScrollPane` in this part of code to your code like this:

```
  JTable tabel_1 =new JTable();
  tabel_1.setSelectionBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 153, 51));
  JScrollPane tableScroll = new JScrollPane(tabel_1);

  frame.add(tableScroll);
```